# Is there a term for the phenomenon where the same word forms more than one part of speech?

Tags: parts-of-speech

Is there a term for e.g. the lexical symbol "duck"? It is both a verb and a noun, in contemporary use having no apparent connection, and so would appear to be represent two words.

Then, is the a better term than 'lexical symbol' to describe any grouping of letters having some meaning? I just made up lexical symbol because it seemed convenient.

Comment: On the contrary, I would myself appreciate a name for a word that can be only a single POS. Get the idea?

Comment: @Kris, yes, your point will probably keep me awake tonight.

Comment: "a group of letters having some meaning" is what we now call a "word" -- why another name for that? There's a difference between the title and the implication of the body.

Comment: Because words don't have letters. Words have sounds. Letters are only for writing, but illiterate people still have words. And even if it were true, it begs the question of "having some meaning". Meaning is not quantifiable like gasoline.

Comment: @Kris When analysing a string of glyphs, you can recognise a repeated pattern you can decide whether that pattern, e.g. a group of letters, is a word or not in the language you are using.

Comment: Kris would like a term for a word that can be only a single part of speech - unlike "like," "term," "word," "can," or "single."

Hmmm...

_I try to pen a sentence_ /

_Free from homonyms_ /

_But when I count, it's just too wild_ /

_How many I've left in..._   (I'd like to know that term for "unhomophonic" as well)

Comment: Heteronym? Nah.

Comment: The word 'duck' is not the best possible example.  In  Etymonline [https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=duck] you will see that the two are not strictly homonymous.  There is a homonymous 'duck', derived from Dutch 'doek', referring to a kind of fabric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[In linguistics, a homonym is, in the strict sense, one of a group of words that share the same spelling and the same pronunciation but have different meanings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym)

Answer (score 5):

At http://www.thefreedictionary.com/duck, both the AHDEL and Collins claim that there are four English words 'duck'. They distinguish them by right-superscripts (which device is restricted to such analyses, of course).

The one they both choose to label duck³ (a heavy cotton fabric) is obviously not related to the other three – this is a case of convergent evolution, from different sources. Different etymologies.

Although words 1, 2 and 4 are obviously etymologically related to each other (word 4 in a punning way), they are still considered to have diverged sufficiently to be classed as three further isoformal words (same spelling;  these also have the same pronunciation) - **homonyms** (strict definition).

However, if we delve deeper, and look, for instance, at AHDEL's treatment of duck³, we see that it lists two (closely related) senses (admittedly one existing only in the plural form and the other almost invariably in the singular) – ONE the material and TWO clothing (usually trousers) made from that material. These senses are classed as **not** being separate words. Different senses of the same word are known as **polysemes**. An obvious example: to play football, you need a football.

Sadly, I have not come across a consensus on whether **polysemy** is a term that is allowed to be applied to isoformal / homographic orthographic words of different word-classes (eg house (n) and house (v); round (preposition) and round (adj) etc).

Oh, and in answer to the second question – an **orthographic word** is 'a meaningful (within the parameters of the language being used) string of letters bounded by spaces'.
The term **lexeme** covers 'families' of 'the same word' , so **man** = **man** *&* **men**; **go** = **go**, **goes** ...

Edwin Ashworth

Comment: Nice answer. Some grammars regard polysemy as necessarily a feature of the same lexeme. So CaGEL, for example and even Aarts (if my memory serves me correctly) would regard lexemes of *different* categories (as opposed to ones which may or may not be of different categories) as not being polysemes but homonyms. So we get descriptions such as *we would regard this as a case of homonymy not polysemy, becasue X1 is a determiner and X2 is an adjective*, for example.

Comment: @Araucaria I added an answer (and got told off for giving two 'answers') below when I found the term 'intercategorial polysemy' months later. But as you say, it depends on how 'word' and 'lexeme' (which Crystal introduced to try to clear up the confusion!) are defined.

Comment: Can I cite you on the Crystal? I never knew that. UCL, seems to have been a hotbed for stuff like that. It never, ever ceases to amaze me.

Comment: Am about to go AFTK (newly learned newspeak), but if if you have any nice refs for either the Crystal or the intercategorial polysemes, I'd be very grateful. (can't find much doing cursory IP search on google)

Comment: Quote me? Certainly not. [Andrew Moore's teaching resource site](https://www.teachit.co.uk/armoore/lang/semantics.htm) has: << Words and lexemes
As a lexical unit may contain more than one word, David Crystal has coined the term _lexeme_. This is usually a single word, but may be a phrase in which the meaning belongs to the whole rather than its parts, as in verb phrases tune in, turn on, drop out or noun phrase[s] (a) cock up, [ship of the desert].>> You can find references for "intercategorial polysemy" in a Google search.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't feel at all safe relying on Andrew Moore's teaching resource site that Crystal coined the term *lexeme*, especially since doing some more cursory research on it. Re intercategorial polysemy, that's a very different concept from there being intercategorial polysemes in the sense of a singe word being in several categories - as opposed to (as I understand it, though I may well be very wrong) an etymological root being the same root with the same meaning and existing in different words in different categories. But, like I said, I may well be wrong.

Comment: @Araucaria This is probably the/'a more' primary source of the Crystal attribution: [The Study of Language_George Yule (2006; CUP)_Semantics ...](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Uoc41AHWvwMC&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=%22David+Crystal+has+coined+the+term+lexeme.%22&source=bl&ots=Jy5v0evKNZ&sig=YkkvLihf7yonq2cXOi5laaSEtiI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRlrPvtMLLAhWB7RQKHd2cDWAQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=%22David%20Crystal%20has%20coined%20the%20term%20lexeme.%22&f=false).

Comment: ... As regards 'intercategorial polysemy' being used to describe words with the same etymology being used as different POSs: The sense is clear in this extract from [Conceptual integration and intercategorial polysemy_Zawada_Language Matters: Studies in the Languages of Africa

Volume 38, Issue 1, 2007](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10228190701640124?journalCode=rlms20):  '... a variety of instances of intercategorial polysemy, ...

Comment: for example in N–V alternations such as _sail_ and _ache_, as well as an example of A–N–V alternation, namely _wide_.' [I had to think about _wide_ used as a verb: as per cricket umpires.] This debate essentially boils down to the 'What is a word?' (and now the 'What is a lexeme?') debate.

Comment: Thanks!!! I'm going to stick that Crystal bit into the piece I'm working on. Right now.

Comment: Glad to Clear that up.

Comment: Is your sign-off at the end of this post there for a special reason?

Comment: I think I thought I'd better show that the overview is my own attempt to make sense of the situation, messy as that situation is – not from someone with real clout.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your reply.  (Hence the late response) I'd consider you as someone with real clout, but okay.

Answer (score 2):

I've come across the term "**intercategorial polysemy**" used in lexicography and cognitive linguistics for the form of polysemy where the same orthographic word (and with the same etymology - not a homonym) is used in different word-class usages.

Thus **bank** (your money) and **bank** (where you bank it) ... but not **bank** (a steep natural incline).

Or **bank** (a steep natural incline) and **bank** (to border or protect with a ridge or embankment) ... but not **bank** (where you put your money).

This would make **lecture** (n) and **lecture** (v) say *intercategorial polysemes*.

Comment: Did you forget that you already answered almost exactly this?

Comment: _Intercategorial polysemy_ is a compound. Are you saying that _wolf_ and _werewolf_ don't warrant different entries in a dictionary? And it does look like it is the correct answer, after all.

Comment: You have multiple much more distinct words in your first answer. Adding a modifier to one of them doesn't warrant a full separate entry. Unless of course you want to do the work to separate your other answer. Just move this to the 'polysemy' paragraph in your other answer.

Comment: @Mitch I couldn't disagree more.

Comment: Do you have a source I could use in relation to this?

Comment: @Araucaria In what way do you disagree? (its hard to know what given that I said multiple things).

Comment: @Mitch The source request was for the author of the post--which was worth reading.

Comment: @Araucaria Oh. My mistake. that part deleted from my comment (as will this comment soon)

Answer (score 0):

Homophony - words sound the same but have different meanings
Homography - words are written the same but have different meanings
Polysemy - more than one sense to a word or sentence

"I'll not be the first president of the United States to lose the war"
Is polysemic, has 2 meanings, even though there's no homophony of homography

"Fan"
Homography - a ventilator or an admirer?

Sorry I can't give you and example of homophony, I only have exemples in Portuguese.

Whenever a signifier has more than one possible sense, it is polysemic (so it would apply to homophony and homography), but polysemy doesn't require homophony and homography to happen