# Words that are members of multiple classes of words (without changing form)

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives

By "class of word" I mean a noun, verb, adjective, adverb etc. This notation came from reading the definitions of these words themselves. For example

> **[noun](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/noun)** *grammar* any member of a class of words that can function as a ...
>
> **[verb](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/verb)** *grammar* any member of a class of words that function as the main elements of predicates, that typically express action ...

By "not changing form", I mean the noun, adjective, verb etc. forms are spelled (and possibly pronounced) exactly the same. An example that doesn't fit this would be **late**, which is an adjective and has an adverb form of **lately**.

I thought of the example word 'complex' last night and wondered if there were a noun that encompasses such words.

**[com·plex](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/complex)**  [adj., v. kuhm-pleks, kom-pleks; n. kom-pleks]

***adjective*** 1 - composed of many interconnected parts; compound; composite: *a complex highway system*.

***noun*** 6 - an intricate or complicated association or assemblage of related things, parts, units, etc.: the entire complex of our educational system; an apartment complex.

And in researching this, I discovered that there is also a verb form of complex specific to chemistry:

***verb (used with object)*** 12 - Chemistry . to form a complex with.

This leads to using a situation where a the word in question can be repeated immediately in a sentence and still be grammatically correct (but admittedly confusing).

> *My apartment is part of a complex complex.*

Interestingly, I found a [brain teaser game](http://www.sporcle.com/games/puckett86/homonyms) which fits what I was looking for, providing 24 other examples, but doesn't define things any more precisely. I also found this [interesting tutorial](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-adjective.htm) covering the case where nouns are used in their exact *nounal* meaning but take the place of an adjective in a sentence. One of their examples: **horse race**.

So my question is this: Is there a word which describes or defines words such as these exactly? It would have a definition like this:

> <***mystery word***> *noun*
>
> 1. A word which itself may function as various parts of grammar without changing spelling or meaning.
> 2. A word which has reached such widespread usage that it has definitions or meanings as a noun, verb, adjective, and/or adverb, all of which have the same origin or root word.
> 3. A word that is a homonym of itself.

I have thought of and dismissed *homonym*, *homograph*, *homophone* etc. because they stipulate variously that the spelling, pronunciation or both are the same but differ in meaning and/or origin. I'm specifically looking for words that sound and are spelled the same and **also** have the same (or very similar) meaning and origin.

Excellent examples from the quiz I linked *(spoiler alert)*:

- I have a sore sore.
- That mammoth is mammoth!
- I've never told anyone the combination, so my safe is still safe.

Comment: And before anyone asks, yes I have read the [comic about the dictionary genie](http://www.smbc-comics.com/?id=2803). :-) (Other comics on that site are offensive/explicit/not-safe-for-work.)

Comment: In English, at least, the term you are looking for is ***word***.

Comment: @StoneyB *rimshot*

Comment: We've covered this before: **intercategorial polyseme**.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth found your [previous answers](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58494), but that question didn't turn up in my search and is pretty explicitly about homonyms. If you want to copy/paste your latter answer and link it to a reference or definition, I'd be glad to accept it. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @PatrickM Since you found that Edwin's answer also answered your own question, I'm going to mark this question as a duplicate of that one. It doesn't mean that you asked a bad question by any means. If you have any questions, please feel free to ping me in chat.